# Minimum of a complex function with various constraints

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, nonlinear-optimization, several-complex-variables

Let $a\in \mathbb{C}$ be a fixed parameter. We condider the domain in $\mathbb{C}^3$  :
$$S = \{ (z_1, z_2, z_3) \in \mathbb{C}^3 , \mathrm{Re} (z_i) \leq \frac 12   \}$$

I would like to prove that the minimum of the function
$$f(z_1,z_2, z_3) = \mathrm{max} (|z_1 z_2 |, |z_2 z_3| , |z_1 z_3| )$$
on $S$, subject to the constraint
$$z_1+z_2+z_3 -1- a\cdot z_1\cdot z_2\cdot z_3 = 0$$
is attained when $z_1 = z_2 = z_3$.

I feel that I'm perhaps missing an obvious simplification to reduce the problem. I thought about using Lagrange multipliers, but it gets pretty messy.

So, any help will be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Your definition of $S_a$ is missing $a$... so unless I'm missing something that set is always the same?

Comment: As @QC_QAOA mentions: You probably want to include the "... subject to the constraint: ..." into your definition of $S_a$, right?

Comment: Indeed, I changed the formulation of the problem before posting and forgot to remove the "a" in $S_a$